# How to resolve the email address of Exchange Server 2003 using WebDAV code

Tags: c#, webdav, exchange-server-2003

I have developed one application which used to send/receive mails using [Exchange Server 2003](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Exchange_Server#Exchange_Server_2003), so in the email input box, if we enter any user's first name and click on some short cut key, I want to resolve that email address.

For example,

1. Type "Pardha" in the input box
2. Press <kbd>cltl</kbd> +<kbd>r</kbd> (short cut key)
3. it should search in Exchange Server 2003 whose names starts with "Pardha", and it should resolve my emaild id as `pardha@testserver.com`
4. If there are multiple users having the same name, then it should display the "select email id" dialog box to select the required email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exchange is the wrong place to search for users of the domain. Perform an ANR search on the Active Directory.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180837(v=vs.80).aspx for sample code.

Comment: **Thanks for your reference**, *i have acheived what i am looking for*